# Creating an XML file with JavaScript and encountering an encoding error - any way to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, xml, encoding

I'm dynamically creating an XML file from a database in server-side JavaScript. The definition of the XML output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

When I try to open the XML in Chrome it reports an encoding error in this name:

```
Balanzó
```

I'm assuming it doesn't think the last character in that person's name is a valid utf-8 character.

Is there some general conversion of text I can do to replace such characters with something that won't cause an encoding error?

Or is there perhaps a "looser" definition of what the XML encoding is I can define that won't cause an error when opening up in a browser to examine the XML?

Thanks,

doug

Comment: have you tried "utf-16"?

Comment: I just tried changing the specification in the prolog to utf-16 and regenerated the XML and Chrome reports an error at the exact same character. I really don't know what to do. I don't know myself for sure if that character happens to be utf-8 encoded or not. It looks like an accented o. But what if it really was initially ISO-8859-1. I am stuck when it comes to this. Right now all I can think of doing is replacing that character with an unaccented o. But that's not right. And I'll probably run into other similar characters.

Comment: You are simply saying: "here comes some UTF-8". And Chrome answers: "that's not true". Imagine that you're e.g. sending a PDF file: it's clear that declaring it as "Music encoded as MP3" won't make it play. You absolutely need to find out what your data encoding is; trying to make Chrome ignore the errors is pointless.

Comment: I do realize that. :) However, I don't understand how. Obviously some user names got stored in different encodings. If I change that 1 character to an unaccented "o" the entire file validates. But what I'm asking here is whether there is a way of checking these characters, as I am building the XML, in order to ensure they are valid utf-8 characters. Otherwise the only thing I can think of is to hunt them down one-by-one and do a replace with an unaccented character while generating the XML. I am lost here. I understand why the XML won't validate. I just really don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Try to post some codes showing how you generate the file, and ask on how to generate XML with utf-16 or any other encoding that support special characters you have. I know how to do it in .NET, so I guess there must be a way to do the same in the programming language you currently use.

Comment: The problem isn't the XML file generation. The problem is that there truly are some characters in the database I'm reading from which were originally stored as ISO-8859-1. Later on the forums site which uses the database started using UTF-8. Everything entered after that is fine. (con't)

Comment: But there are a couple of hundred entries containing user names like "André" which are clearly encoded in ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8. If I look at the page after forcing the browser to ISO-8859-1 I see the accented "e" character fine. If I force the page back to UTF-8 it is clearly an invalid character. And if I edit the user's profile and make sure the character is correct that record validates just fine in UTF-8. (con't)

Comment: But how can I algorithmically find all the data which was in ISO-8859-1 so I can modify it, even if I have to manually fix each entry in the database? I don't know an algorithm for determining whether a given string is valid UTF-8 or not. Is there such an algorithm? That is now the crux of the problem.

Comment: Is there at least a validator I can drop the entire XML into which will report on each line containing an encoding error? If I do it in FireFox or Chrome it just reports on the first encountered error. I can then fix that in the data, re-generate the XML, reload in the browser, find the next error and fix that, etc. That means generating and reading the file in the browser hundreds of times. Is there some tool at least which can show me all the encoding errors at once?

Comment: You'll have to convert the data in your database to utf-8 first. It can be a mess if you have mysql with the wrong table/database collation. Some other database makes it easier to convert things to other encoding... but it's an other question that is already answered on SO.

Comment: This is a NoSQL database. But the problem is that most of the site is already UTF-8, there are just some invalid characters here and there. I need to track down which characters are invalid and fix them. So I am looking for an algorithm, in JavaScript (our server-side language which talks directly with the database) so I can do this.